# Finding which items have at least one common value with other items

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, set

I have the following collection :

```
var items = new[] 
{
    new { Name = "A", Values = new [] { 20, 4, 5, 9, 3, 22 } },
    new { Name = "B", Values = new [] { 10, 7, 9, 8, 42 } },
    new { Name = "C", Values = new [] { 11, 103, 0 } },
    new { Name = "D", Values = new [] { 7, 35, 42 } }
};
```

I would like to find which items have at least one common integer value with the others items. For example, "A" has 9 in common with "B", so "A" and "B" are related each other.

At the end, this should be the result :

```
A => [B]
B => [A, D]
C => []
D => [B]
```

I wrote this code :

```
var tuples = items 
    .SelectMany(x => x.Values, (x, y) => new { x.Name, Value = y })
    .ToList();  

var result = tuples.Join(tuples, 
           x => x.Value, 
           x => x.Value, 
           (x, y) => new { NameA = x.Name, NameB = y.Name })        
    .Distinct()
    .GroupBy(x => x.NameA, x => x.NameB, 
        (a, b) => new { Name = a, Overlaps = b.Where(x => x != a)) });
```

It works (and return expected results). I was wondering if there would be a more efficient (faster and with a lower memory footprint) way do to it. I wanted to use `GroupJoin()` but since I need to filter out duplicate values (using Distinct) I used `Join()` instead.

Comment: Regarding the on-topicness of the question and the rollbacks around it. As per meta policy answers to off-topic questions are not considered for the purposes of evaluating rollback criteria. As such fixing the code to make the question on topic is **always** acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

For set-based operations like this it's better to use [`HashSet<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8).

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations.

The items can easily be converted to ones containing `HashSet`s. Then, the `Overlaps` method does the comparison:

```cs
var hashed = items
    .Select(i => new { Name = i.Name, Values = i.Values.ToHashSet() })
    .ToList();
var overlaps = hashed.Select(h1 => new
{
    h1.Name,
    Overlaps = hashed
        .Where(h2 => h2.Name != h1.Name && h2.Values.Overlaps(h1.Values))
        .Select(h => h.Name)
});
```

Result:

```
A => B 
B => A,D 
C   
D => B
```

Of course, if possible, it would be better to create items with `HashSet`s at the outset.

**EDIT**

Triggered by your comment I did some benchmarking. I blew up your array a 1000 times, keeping unique names and then just measured both methods, using Linqpad:

```cs
var items = Enumerable.Range(1,1000).SelectMany(e =>  new[]
{
    new { Name = "A" + e, Values = new [] { 20, 4, 5, 9, 3, 22 } },
    new { Name = "B" + e, Values = new [] { 10, 7, 9, 8, 42 } },
    new { Name = "C" + e, Values = new [] { 11, 103, 0 } },
    new { Name = "D" + e, Values = new [] { 7, 35, 42 } }
});

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var hashed = items.Select(i => new { Name = i.Name, Values = i.Values.ToHashSet() }).ToList();

sw.Elapsed.Dump();

var overlaps = hashed.Select(h1 => new
{
    h1.Name,
    Overlaps = hashed
        .Where(h2 => h2.Name != h1.Name && h2.Values.Overlaps(h1.Values))
        .Select(h => h.Name).ToList()
}).ToList();
sw.Stop();
sw.Elapsed.Dump();

sw.Restart();
var tuples = items
    .SelectMany(x => x.Values, (x, y) => new { x.Name, Value = y })
    .ToList();

sw.Elapsed.Dump();
var result = tuples.Join(tuples,
           x => x.Value,
           x => x.Value,
           (x, y) => new { NameA = x.Name, NameB = y.Name })
    .Where(x => x.NameA != x.NameB)
    .Distinct()
    .GroupBy(x => x.NameA, x => x.NameB)
    .ToList();
sw.Stop();
sw.Elapsed.Dump();
```

The results:

```
00:00:00.0035664
00:00:02.0326684
00:00:00.0029370
00:00:06.3872002
```

As you see, the preparatory actions for both methods are done in 'no time', but the hashset-based method is considerably faster. Interestingly, if I blow up the arry 2000 times, the hashset-based method takes 7.7s and your method throws an `OutOfMemoryException` on my box.

Side note: if I don't make the names unique both methods are comparable. (On which I based my previous comment).

Comment: I tried your solution and it is much slower than original one. `Overlaps()` is not the issue. Bottleneck is the two inner loops on `hashed`. It is basically `O(n^2)`

Comment: OK, I didn't really have data to benchmark this, but then, I didn't expect this because the hashset comparison itself is really fast. It may turn out that your `SelectMany` version is the most efficient/scalable way to do it because `Join`'s time complexity is O(n).

Comment: If I blow up your items array 2000 times I get comparable results as for execution time (adding `ToList` to the inner `Select` to force execution). Did you notice that I added `ToList()` later to the creation of `hashed`? Anyway, comparable results is nothing like "faster", so if I can't think of any improvement I'll leave this answer here for reference, but of course it's not acceptable.

Comment: Please check my test code [here](https://gist.github.com/tigrouind/eb763f2d58214a6a33c6bfaca94c612f). Your solution is considerably slower. I am not sure why it differs from results you got.

Comment: It seems that the chance of overlaps is decisive here. When there are no overlaps, HashSet.Overlaps has to exhaust both sets to come to a conclusion, while `Join` benefits from fewer overlaps. However, when the number of items in the arrays increases (take max 40) then the hashset-based method gets the better one. So it seems to depends much on content and it's yours to decide which method suits you best. I think one advantage of my method is that it's less complex (more self-explanatory) and it seems to have a better memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

I would make use of `Intersect()`, which, when combined with `Any()`, compares two lists of values and returns `true` if any matching values exist. I tested it and it runs significantly faster.

Separating and storing all the name-value pair combinations in memory seems overly costly and unnecessary.

```
var result = items.Select(x => new 
{ 
    x.Name, 
    Related = items.Where(y => 
                              y.Name != x.Name 
                              && 
                              y.Values.Intersect(x.Values).Any()
                         )
                         .Select(y => y.Name) 
});
```

Comment: This is \$O(n^2)\$, so it'll perform significantly worse for larger numbers of items. You'll only notice when you actually start enumerating the results (and their `Related` properties) though, due to the 'lazy' nature of `Select`.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet is O(n) even possible?

Comment: I think tigrou's solution is \$O(n)\$, with \$n\$ being the total number of values. `Join`, `Distinct` and `GroupBy` will use some sort of hash-based lookup internally, so they should all be \$O(n)\$.